# CSS Accordion in AngularJS with no directive - fixed height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-animations

I was hoping to prove how cool and easy AngularJS is with a small Accordion example, the whole thing is pretty simple, in my Controller I have an array and I have a ng-repeat where I bind some data and apply a css rule when the $index of the ng-repeat matches a scope variable. It's all simple stuff like so, here is my controller (I've reduced some of the text for this example).

```
$scope.paymentTypes = [
  {name: 'Visa', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper ac sem non molestie. Mauris eu tempor nisi. Praesent vitae porta lectus. Maecenas risus eros, feugiat eget vehicula at!'},
  {name: 'Master Card', text: 'Mauris eu tempor nisi. Praesent vitae porta lectus. Maecenas risus eros, feugiat eget vehicula at, scelerisque ac nisi. Nunc tristique, ipsum eu gravida dignissim, lacus turpis dapibus enim, ut viverra neque sem ac lectus. Sed sit amet auctor est. Nulla sit amet felis magna.'}, 
  {name: 'Paypal', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper ac sem non molestie. Mauris eu tempor nisi. Praesent vitae porta lectus. Maecenas risus eros, feugiat eget vehicula at, scelerisque ac nisi. Nunc tristique, ipsum eu gravida dignissim, lacus turpis dapibus enim, ut viverra neque sem ac lectus. Sed sit amet auctor est. Nulla sit amet felis magna.'}, 
  {name: 'Bitcoin', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper ac sem non molestie.'}];

$scope.selectedType = null;

$scope.togglePayments = function (index) {
  if ($scope.selectedType === index) {
    $scope.selectedType = null;
  } else {
    $scope.selectedType = index;
  }
}
```

and here is my ng-repeat in my view...

```
<div data-ng-repeat="ptype in paymentTypes track by $index" data-ng-click="togglePayments($index)">
  <div class="row u-padding-vert-s">
    <div class="col-xs-6 payment-type" data-ng-bind="ptype.name"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"><!-- put a logo here later --></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row u-slide-down" data-ng-hide="selectedType !== $index">
    <div class="col-xs-12" data-ng-bind="ptype.text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 u-border-top-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 toggle-tab text-center">
      <span class="icon-ic_list_arrow_down"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 u-border-top-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css I have created to prove the sliding open and close animation:

```
.u-slide-down {
  transition: .3s linear all;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellowgreen;
  height: 200px;
}

.u-slide-down.ng-hide {
  height: 0px;
}
```

Pretty cool, however this example relies on all hidden divs being the same height. In the real world I would prefer the hidden div to be flexible with its height and be more dynamic! As the content is different and may even contain HTML at some point. Now when I set my css to `height: auto;` in the `.u-slide-down` class the animation is lost. I don't want to have to write a directive for this as I want my example to be as simple as possible, so can anyone suggest what I can do to my CSS to allow dynamic heights and retain the animation? In the meantime, I'll try to put something together in https://jsbin.com... give me a sec!